# How can I get an SPList's URL?

Tags: list, powershell

Say I have a list named Links. Is there a way, through .NET and Powershell, to retrieve the URL for this list? In this case, the URL I'm looking for would be "/Lists/Links".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SPList.RootFolder.Url` will give you the site relative URL.  You might have to add a **/** to the beginning.

Comment: Doesn't work in some situations esp. in PowerShell. I get blank back. The ServerRelativeUrl property helps though.

Comment: Rob Nicholson you r right. its not giving relative url in powershell. As you told ServerRelativeUrl  property worked for me. thanks